# HQL | Getting a Map as a result

Tags: hibernate, dictionary

I have a pojo Person with fields: id/name/age/gender.

I wish to get a map returned from HQL with Person.id as the key and the Person object as the value.
What should the HQL look like?

I have tried this:

```
select new map(p.id,new Person(p.name,p.age,p.gender)) from Person
```

Is this the correct way to get the required result?
I want to avoid doing the java based manipulation for preparing the map out of the received results.

Answer (score 3):

Use this HQL:

```
select new map(p.id, p ) from Person p
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. With `select new ...` for each row the constructor is executed, you get one instance per row, and query.list() provides you with a list of these instances.

You have to write the java code for reading each row of the list and putting it into a map. That's only a few lines of code. (Or you write your own map implementation with a constructor which accepts a id column and a list as parameters, and you do the manipulations there, but that is probably more complicated.)